# How to unambiguously identify a Model as a lowercase string in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to pass a model name as an URL parameter, so I can use it to access a specified model class in my view. For example:

> /app_label/model_name

and in *views.py*:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
```

The problem is - I want my url to be case-insensitive. Therefore, I cannot just use the code above, because one of the models can look like these below:

> MyModel, MySuperModel, MyAwesomeSuperModel

Is there any way to identify a Model unambiguously as a lowercase string?

I thought about using *table_name* however it would mean looping over every model in the project each time a request is processed. Not very efficient.

Comment: If you want the url to be case-insensitive, then you should not use model class names which differ only by case in their names, and so there would not be any ambiguity.

Comment: If you don't have too many models you could create a dictionary mapping model canonical names to the models themselves... There may be a DRYer way to do it out there, but this would be quick and easy.

Comment: I want to create a generic solution (a reusable app), so I do not control how many models are out there or what are their names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you will have to iterate over app's models list but you can cache it:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.db.models import get_app, get_models

APPS_MODELS = {}

def get_model(app_name, model_name):

    app_models = APPS_MODELS.get(app_name)
    if app_models:
        return app_models.get(model_name)

    try:
        app = get_app(app_name)
    except ImproperlyConfigured: # no such app
        return None

    APPS_MODELS[app_name] = dict((model._meta.model_name, model)
                                     for model in get_models(app))

    return APPS_MODELS[app_name].get(model_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_model_object.__class__.__name__.lower()
```

gives you the lower case name of model name if it can help you